# Which Rogers internet compatible router is most secure?

Tags: router, zero-day

Without telling you which specific Rogers-provided router, version, nor the terrible but verified security bug that exists for it (them), would any dear somewhat security conscious Rogers customer here please provide an alternative, and hopefully more secure, modem to use with Rogers?

Actually, to switch the router to another make and model was recommended to me by Rogers internet staff themselves.

It isn't fixed, and since I seem to have no way to be able to update the firmware by myself, I'm assuming this is 0day.

This all seems too crazy to be true - that they've let this slide for a number of months now, without knowing about it - both the original manufacturer, and more so Rogers.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some more clarity, perhaps provide some references and show your current research to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of placing your trust in Rogers (or any internet provider), you can certainly take responsibility for your own security.  Purchase your own router/firewall appliance, and connect all your home machines to it.  Then connect your router to the Rogers router.  That way, even if your Rogers' router is compromised, the infection remains isolated outside of your devices.

Inexpensive routers are widely available.  And if you still don't trust them, you can purchase the kind that lets you replace its firmware with an open source alternative, like OpenWRT or Tomato.

While there may not be much difference between a Rogers router and a cheap router, keep in mind that most router attacks are perpetrated by attackers who are using robots to sweep millions of machines looking for vulnerabilities.  Once the robots find them, the thief enters the network and sees what they can steal.  If they break through your Rogers' router and find only another firewall, they may decide your system is not worth their time to attack.

Comment: I see that adding that layer would be more beneficial.  Even if any answer provides a currently more measurably secure router, there is no guarantee that the recommended one will stay the more secure one in the future, or that it won't have a terrible 0day exposed for a long time.  Thanks for the quick answer.